# Parental Controls

Tags: software-recommendation, internet, parental-controls

Just updated my son's PC with saucy & wondered if there is a simple way of adding parental controls to it.

I looked into DansGuardian but I don't have a server, and I'm not well versed in configuring the program.

Is there something simple & easy to use/install like Windows Family Safety or Norton Family Safety that doesn't take much configuring (like OpenDNS)?

Comment: open DNS works on Linux and is probably your bestoption

Comment: As  bodhi.zazen said open DNS should be a good option *but* if your son is savvy, he will be able to change the DNS([D]omain [N]ame [S]erver-like a phone book for internet domains) without any trouble unless you only give him a limited(non admin) account, but then any games or programs that are not installed locally(includes anything from the Software Center) will need you to enter the password to allow it...may be a drawback to you or a plus, depending on how much control you want him to have over his computer.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to restrict access to adult content?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/158572/what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-access-to-adult-content)

Answer (score 0):

OpenDNS is good, then there is Gnome Nanny which is also good (its the most similar to Windows programs), but I've read that it only works with select browsers, so not perfect...

Also there is WebContentControl which is designed to help with configuring DansGaurdian, and other apps.