# How do I block everything on a user account, except Firefox?

Tags: parental-controls

I'm trying out Ubuntu on some work PCs, but I'd like everything to be blocked on the users account, except Firefox and Flash Player. Essentially a parental controls application, but for the system/applications.

Comment: read this conversation it might help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/158572/what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-access-to-adult-content

Comment: You didn't tell us the reason, but would possibly the guest session feature be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:  use a nonstandard window manager (fwm, twm, flwm...) and write a custom configuration file that starts Firefox maximized by default upon login, doesn't show anything else, and doesn't expose a menu for anything except Firefox or logoff.

If using GNOME: most menu icons come from /usr/share/applications, so delete (or make not world-readable) any that you don't want target user(s) to see icons for.  Add back permissions for yourself (or other specific users) using "setfacl" or a "powerusers" group or something.

In GNOME, you'll also need to disable the "run..." key combination (otherwise a user could run "xterm", have a shell, and start anything).  See  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27518/how-to-fully-lock-the-gnome-panel for how to lock the panel after you remove everything that could be used to escape to a shell.