# How do I set up parental controls on Tahr?

Tags: software-recommendation, parental-controls

> Keep in mind that this question is **not asking for merely a time limiter!** Please read the full question and see that **I also want to limit application and internet access**. The solution doesn't have to be one single application, but it does have to be automatic enough that a technically illiterate person wouldn't have to fiddle with it.

---

> Migrated to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11184/how-do-i-set-up-parental-controls-on-tahr) as requested

---

I'm completely aghast at the lack of parental controls in Tahr, and how even [Ubuntu.com's suggestions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ParentalControls) are so out-of-date that some are impossible now.

I need something that will:

- Allow **general computer time** to be limited
- Allow **application access** to be limited (searching, installing, and running)
- Allow **internet browsing** time to be limited (might also cover most of the above point)
- Allow sites to be **blocked** *without* manually maintaining a list
- Allow specific sites to be **whitelisted**
- **NOT** set up or connect to a proxy or alternative DNS, as we're with Comcast and they're very keen to drop service at the slightest hint of alternative internet usage

I **can't use** something like:

- **Timekpr**, **Timoutd**, or **Nanny**, as they're no longer available or supported
- **OpenDNS** as I don't know how Comcast will treat that. Even if they don't mind at first, their actions going forward seem to show they won't be kind to it sometime soon.
- **Scrubit** because our modem/router is rented from Comcast.

Comment: also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/158572/what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-access-to-adult-content

Comment: @Takkat I also want to restrict websites and programs. I already looked at the linked question, but its answers are all outdated. That's why I put **Tahr** in the title of this question

Comment: Yeah, I do realize that but there is not much news since. However I updated my timekpr answer there to include the new fork for 14.04. All website filter I know of are terribly outdated. The best may be Dansguardian but still... Whitelists are a pain to maintain, so no option for a computer illiterate daddy. You may have some luck with a browser based content filter but only until the kid becomes smart enough to break it (which likely is pretty soon).

Comment: Consider migrating your question to Software Recommendations if you don't find any answer satisfactory.

Comment: @Braiam uh... I _did_ tag it `software-recommendation`

Comment: Your question is being closed by too-broad and duplicated here. So obviously people thinks you are asking the same question or your requirements aren't too specific, that's why I suggested migration. I see the question just fine for SR.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so rude when I wrote these comments. I'm not sure why I was so, but I regret it nonetheless. I hope to be much kinder here on in.

Comment: This spawned Ubuntu bug [#1501816](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1501816).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Timekpr is available for 14.04 still according to this article [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/timekpr-restrict-computer-access-ubuntu)

Comment: Does the new version satisfy all of my requirements?

Comment: Is the computer yours or your childs or is it a family shared computer? If it is yours you could setup a separate user account and make them a non admin so they would need your password to install software. If it is there computer you could always setup a password that only you know. Also I am not sure what the applications limitations are as I do not use it sorry.

Comment: The computer is my cousin's. He's about 8 years old, now. His father is technologically illiterate (he doesn't even know what an OS is, much less Linux). If you don't know what the application you linked does, then I'll have to vote your answer down as not helpful, because that means you just posted a link without knowing what it is you linked.

Comment: I read the article and I know that it gives the ability to restrict the times a computer can be used, it is not an activity or site blocker only basically an application that can restrict time. Web browsers have the ability to control site restrictions so in conjunction with Timekpr this would do all you wanted.

Comment: @rstreerer78 alright. I can't accept your answer until it actually answers my full question, but thank you for doing research.

Comment: To you, I'm also sorry for being so rude when I wrote _these_ comments. I'm not sure why I was so, but I regret it nonetheless. I hope to be much kinder here on in.