# Parental Control on wifi

Tags: wireless, parental-controls

I'm providing a wifi signal inside my house for my children.

Is there a way of filtering the sites they can visit ?
or... Is there a way I can watch the sites they are visiting ?

I don't have a router.
I created a WiFi Hotspot as described here: 
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu-16-04-android-supported/

Comment: An addon for Firefox may be a good start to filter inadvertent access to bad sites - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxfilter/ But there's also some trust involved with this, as anyone who really wants to see something can get it. For any solution you'd also have to block VPN's, proxies, tor, google cache, circumvent incognito/private mode, etc. It's a lot harder for you to think of every possible problem and block it than for them to think of one exploit and get around you. If China's Great Firewall can be beat, so can you.

Comment: Also see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/158572/what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-access-to-adult-content?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

There are three options:

- Set up parental controls with your ISP  (not sure if possible, and will also affect you)
- Set up something on your router (depends on your model etc), or add another transparent proxy in your network (e.g. raspberry pi)
- Set up parental control on your child's devices (not sure which ones they use, etc)

You need to provide more details to see which of those options make sense